# org.apache.olingo path is not resolved even after downloading the dependencies

Tags: java, rest, maven, odata, olingo

I am trying to create an OData service using apache olingo V4 (https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata4/tutorials/read/tutorial_read.html)

But when I am creating an Edm(Entity Data Model) provider class by inheriting the class **CsdlAbstractEdmProvider** of the package **org.apache.olingo.commons.api.edm.provider** (https://olingo.apache.org/javadoc/odata4/org/apache/olingo/commons/api/edm/provider/CsdlAbstractEdmProvider.html), getting the error **The import org.apache can not be resolved**

I understand that, I am missing the necessary library to be included in my project. Though I have created this as maven project and edited the **pom.xml** file as suggested in the tutorial. Even, to avoid any conflict I am using the same naming conventions for the file as been used in the tutorial.

Please suggest me how to deal with this situation. Feel free to ask about any further clarification about the question. Here I am including my pom.xml file

```
<project
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.group.id</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoService</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>4.0.0</version>

    <name>DemoService Maven Webapp</name>
    <properties>
        <javax.version>2.5</javax.version>
        <odata.version>4.0.0</odata.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.7</slf4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>odata-server-api</artifactId>
            <version>${odata.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>odata-server-core</artifactId>
            <version>${odata.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>odata-commons-api</artifactId>
            <version>${odata.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.olingo</groupId>
            <artifactId>odata-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>${odata.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.11</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>  
    <build>
        <finalName>DemoService</finalName>
    </build>
  </project>
```

Here is the snapshot of my project folder structure
[Project folder structure]

Comment: Do you also get the error when doing `mvn clean compile`? Also, the *runtime* scope for the `odata-server-core` artifact looks suspicious, are you sure this should be runtime and not default?

Comment: Hi @user3151902, thank you very much for your interest. Since I am using Eclipse as my IDE. I am cleaning the project by right clicking on pom.xml file -> Run As -> maven clean. In that case I am getting success message in the console.

Comment: OK, but *maven clean* will only remove compiled files and other Maven output. You can do *File -> Run as -> Maven...* and then enter `clean compile` under *goals*

Comment: Regarding odata-server-core - Since I am referring to the tutorial from apache olingo official website so I am just assuming that everything is standard and up to date. So I avoided making any change in pom.xml file. Anyway I am new in using olingo and maven framework. So if any modification is needed please suggest.

Comment: Done `clean compile` but no effect.

Comment: I suspect there is some issues with mu maven dependency downloading and including them in the project when I go to Java build path (Right Click -> properties -> java Build Path) and then extend the maven dependency, there is no jar related with olingo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem with my maven installation. I installed it separately and set the path variable to C:\ProgramFiles\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin. To be sure you can run `mvn -version` in command prompt(https://maven.apache.org/install.html).

Thank you